# C# Telegram Bot | Handle messages when the thread is sleeping

Tags: c#, async-await, telegram-bot

The bot is being created with "YourEasyBot". I have a "sleeping" thread using Task.Delay(), but i need to check, if a client sends messages while Task is delayed, the bot must answer "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding"

```
async Task ProceedOrder()
{
    Message msg = new();
    msg = await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding\n\nIt won't take more than 3 minutes");

    long time = new Random().NextInt64(10, 181);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(time)));
    if(await NewTextMessage(update) != null){
       await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding");
    }
    await Telegram.DeleteMessageAsync(chat, msg.MessageId);
    msg = await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Done");
}
```

I type a text and it answers "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding" only after the Task.Delay finished. But i need to check NewTextMessage all the time Task.Delay is working. How can i do it?

The expected dialog is:
**Please, wait. Your order is proceeding. It Won't take more than 3 minutes**

- just some text from a client while Task.Delay is working
  **Please, wait. Your order is proceeding**
- another text
  **Please, wait. Your order is proceeding**
  **Done**

Comment: Why is the Task.Delay needed?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the bot is being made in practicing purpose, so it's like emulation of  proceeding order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, you want to check multiple tasks. Either the delay task or the newMessage.

I haven't tested it, (it's already late), it could contain typo's, see it as; That I can point you in the right direction. you could try something like:

```
async Task ProceedOrder()
{
    Message msg = new();

    msg = await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding\n\nIt won't take more than 3 minutes");

    long time = new Random().NextInt64(10, 181);

    // instead of await the task here, store the task in a variable.
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(time)));

    while(true)
    {
        // create a new task to receive a new TextMessage
        var newMessageTask = NewTextMessage(update);
    
        // if any of the tasks is completed, return from the Task.WhenAny.
        // the return value is the task that is completed.
        if(await Task.WhenAny(delayTask, newMessageTask) == delayTask)
            // if it was the delayTask, that means time is passed by, 
            // break out of the while loop
            break;

       // otherwise, the completed task is the newMessageTask
       // send the chatmessage
       await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Please, wait. Your order is proceeding");
    }

    // The delay-time has passed, end it..
    await Telegram.DeleteMessageAsync(chat, msg.MessageId);
    msg = await Telegram.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "Done");
}
```

Comment: Adding ``!delayTask.IsCompleted`` on the while condition might be better?

Comment: Might.. But the Task.WhenAny returns the delayTask when the delayTask is completed. One thing could be when Sending the message takes a "long" ltime, It doesn't startup the NewTextMessage when the delayTask is completed. That would be a benefit  of putting the IsCompleted there. On the other hand, just checking the IsCompleted of a task without await it, might lose any exception thrown in it.

Comment: I was saying just to put the dealyTask.IsCompleted instead of true on the while,  and not change anything, as it goes for exception I think that exceptions thrown by delayTask will still be ignored because we are not calling .Result or awaiting it anywhere.

Comment: You don't need to use the `.Result` to get the exception. `await` is doing that. How would you ever  get an exception on `Task Method()`

Comment: Yeah it doesn't matter what you use outside of the while loop await or .Result as awaiting WhenAny wont give any exception

Comment: This was the base, thanks. I just added cancelation token and everything works fine